# Request method 'GET' not supported

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

Trying to redirect from controller method to another controller, facing below error

**org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'GET' not supported**

I have submitForm method in controller 1, once i call submit method it should call controller 2

**Controller 1**

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView submitForm(@ModelAttribute("loginForm") Login login, BindingResult errors, SessionStatus status, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    return new ModelAndView("path2.sp");    
}
```

**Controller 2**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("path2.sp")
public class DestinationController {
    System.out.println("");
}
```

Comment: You want to call GET method but in your  controller you have only post

Comment: `DestinationController` doesn't even have a method to receive a redirection call from `submitForm` method. Create a method in `DestinationController` that can receive a request call.

Comment: I want to receive request at class level

Comment: DestinationController  does not have any action method?

Comment: action method have dependency on other methods like showForm, initBinder, reference data etc..

Comment: `@ModelAttribute("loginForm") Login login` here you are fetching request from form so you need to send a object to bind that data so you can fetch from `login` object but here spring doesn't knows what data you are trying to fetch

Answer (score 0):

This is not the way to do redirection.

First, fix your `@RequestMapping` in Controller 2, like this:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/path2")
public class DestinationController {
    System.out.println("");
}
```

Now, in controller 1 just do this:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String submitForm(@ModelAttribute("loginForm") Login login, BindingResult errors, SessionStatus status, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    return "redirect:/path2";
}
```

Comment: I did the changes still facing same issue

Comment: can you post your stack trace?